# Specifying linking order of external shared libraries cmake

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I have a project which I am converting from Makefile to cmake, and have issues specifying the linking order of my externally shared libraries.

If within my CMakeLists.txt, I specify (generalised):

```
target_link_libraries(Project
    "$ENV{EXTERN_LIBBIN}/libone.so"
    "$ENV{EXTERN_LIBBIN}/libtwo.so"
    "$ENV{EXTERN_LIBBIN}/libthree.so"
    "$ENV{EXTERN_LIBBIN}/libfour.so")
```

In order for libthree.so to function properly, I need libone.so and libtwo.so to be linked first.

Running ldd Project yields:

```
    libthree.so
    libone.so 
    libtwo.so
    libfour.so
```

How do I force cmake to link external libraries in a particular order?

Comment: I suppose you could create [`IMPORTED`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#imported-targets) targets for those libraries, set the dependencies between them, and use those in your `target_link_libraries`. In that setup, I believe that CMake should retain the correct order.